# Cocos2d-x javascript doesn't work on iOS but does on html5 and android

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I've followed [RayWenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32970/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-game-with-cocos2d-javascript-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial about creating cross platform cocos2d apps using javascript bindings. I know It's not the best and most updated guide out there, but it did the trick for now.

I have setup a project using the cocos2d-iphone with javascript template.

I'm having a problem getting a label's string:

On HTML5 & Android, using:

```
this._labels[i].getString()
```

works just fine, but on iOS, using the exact same code, I get a warning:

`this._labels[i].getString is not a function`

I did notice that switching from get/setString() to accessing label.string directly does work, however, I do want to maintain a single code base, and preferably not access members directly.

**EDIT:**

Same problem with a cocos2d-x 2.1.1 ios project

Comment: Just FYI cocos2d-iphone and cocos2d-x are diverging in JS support. The cocos2d-iphone branch JS binding are no longer maintained and actually have been removed in v3. So simply depending on which version of cocos2d-x you're using these two JS bindings may not be compatible (if they ever were). I'm not even sure whether you really need cocos2d-iphone since cocos2d-x also provides iOS support, so the JS bindings should support JS development for both Android and iOS with JS. Not sure about cocos2d-x level of JS support but cocos2d-iphone + JS is an unmaintained, unpopular dead-end street.

Comment: Yeah, i thought of that after posting this. I get the same issue with a cocos2d-x IOS project